# RavenDB - Index Creation for FullText Search, trying to Project the fields

Tags: c#, ravendb, projection

```
{   "BiImagePrefix": "bi",   "GrImagePrefix": "gr",   "FrameCount": 479,   "RollUid": null,   "Location": null,   "FrameList": [],  
> "Index": {
>     "DocumentType": "OFFICIAL RECORDS",
>     "RollNumber": "2865",
>     "RollTitle": ""   },   
>"IndexList": [
>>    {
>>>       "FrameNumber": 2,
>       "Index": {
>         "$type": "System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Core",
>         "Name": "2865",
>         "Title": "",
>         "Range": "2801-2900"
>       }
>     },
>>>     {
>>       "FrameNumber": 3,
      "Index": {
        "$type": "System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Core",
        "Name": "2865343",
        "Title": "",
        "Range": "233801-2943400"
      }
    }

  ]  }
```

Created following index

```
>     docs.Rolls
>     .SelectMany(roll => roll
>     .Select(token => new {__document_id = roll["@metadata"]["@id"], Name = token.Key,     Value = token.Value, Query = new
> {roll.Index.DocumentType,  roll.IndexList[0].FrameNumber,
> roll.IndexList[0].Index.Name}))
>     .Select(x => new {__document_id = x.__document_id, Name = x.Name, Value = x.Value, Query = x.Query})
```

projeced fields are

```
 1  __document_id   (Stored)
 2  Name    (Stored)
 3  Value     (Analyzed, Stored)
 4 Query    (Stored)
```

Fields inside projected field "Query" works fine if I reference like this:

```
Query = new {roll.Index.DocumentType,  roll.IndexList[0].FrameNumber, roll.IndexList[0].Index.Name}
```

IndexList[0] only projects all the fields of the 1st array element. I wanted to project for all the elements (ie all the FrameNumber) inside "IndexList" array how do i specify that.

I tried for one of the property "FrameNumber" which is inside "IndexList" like this `roll.IndexList.Select(x=>x.FrameNumber)`, and it did not work

How do i solve this issue ?